# using ngRok to tunnel connections to a local Stratum server

Tags: ngrok, stratum

We are using NgRok to tunnel TCP/UDP connection from the internets to the localhost.

However, as you know, stratum has it's own protocol, and subsequently, the url looks something like that:

`stratum://0.tcp.ngrok.io:3333`

NiceHash, our hashes provider, does not recognise it, and thus is unable to connect.

**Some background:**
We are developing a mining pool and would like to test it locally, before deploying to staging / prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at https://github.com/mmatczuk/go-http-tunnel you can host server on GCP and have any dns name you want.

Comment: Did not test but I trust you